# Sed behavior in pandas replace function

Tags: python, pandas

What would be the best way to get sed like behavior from pandas replace functionality?

I have a column that is written as "Last Name, First Name" and I just want to quickly and efficiently convert it to First Name Last Name

I had hoped I could do some sed like expressions in my regex, but that doesn't seem to be supported.

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].replace({'\(.*\),\(.*\)':'\2 \1'},regex=True)
```

I am sure there is a simple way to do this so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use raw strings so that the backslashes will be interpreted by the regexp engine.

Comment: Thanks!  I also was incorrectly escaping the parens in the match, but the following works

`df['Name'] = df['Name'].replace({r'(.*),(.*)':r'\2 \1'},regex=True)`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a rather intuitive method would be to split into a list, and join them back in reverse order.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Smith, John', 'Brown, Bob']})
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.split(',').apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x[::-1]))

print(df)
```

Output

```
          Name
0   John Smith
1    Bob Brown
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  This does work and I like the application.  Barmar showed that I was just not formatting the commands correctly and it should work like I expected.